# Is it possible to make an undecorated `QMainWindow`?

Tags: c++, qt

Is it possible to make an undecorated `QMainWindow`, and if so how can I go about it?

Comment: What does undecorated mean?

Answer (score 1):

Yes,

```
mainWin->setWindowFlags(Qt::CustomizeWindowHint);
```

See [Qt::WindowFlags](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WindowType-enum) and [Window Flags Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-windowflags-example.html)

Answer (score 1):

If by `undecorated` you mean without frame, border etc. then you can probably make use of [`QWidget::setWindowFlags`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#windowFlags-prop)...

```
main_window.setWindowFlags(main_window.windowFlags() | Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
```

Also take a look at a few of the other flags such as `Qt::BypassWindowManagerHint`.

Note that the results you get may depend heavily on your platform and/or window manager.